# Prove that the sum is always greater than $1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+ \frac{1}{n^2} \ge 1$, for all natural numbers $n$.
I tried to use mathematical inducion but failed and I tried to figure out a short formula for the sum but I couldnt find any.

Comment: The smallest is $\frac{1}{n^2}$, and there should be $n^2$ terms

Comment: Ah, almost $n^2$, so this estimate is close to $1$ but not good enough. We need a better approach.

Comment: If we were able to use logarithms then it is easier.

Comment: For $n=2$ we get that the sum equals to \frac{13}{12}

Comment: Well, if there are $n^2$ terms, and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is the smallest, then $\frac{1}{n} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2} \geq \frac{1}{n^2} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2} = n^2 \frac{1}{n^2}=1$ no ?

Comment: One approach: the whole sum from $1$ to $n^2$ is about $C + \log(n^2)$, while the sum from $1$ to $n$ is about $C + \log n$. So in fact this sum is about $\log n$, growing slowly to $\infty$.

Comment: There are in fact $n^2 - n + 1$... so this estimate is a bit too rough...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without integrals. If $n\ge4$
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{n^2}\frac1k>\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac1k+\sum_{k=2n}^{3n-1}\frac1k+\sum_{k=3n}^{4n-1}\frac1k>n\,\frac{1}{2\,n}+n\,\frac{1}{3\,n}+n\,\frac{1}{4\,n}=\frac12+\frac13+\frac14=\frac{14}{12}.
$$

Comment: I like this solution. The sum is so much larger than 1 in general. You can throw out most of it.

Comment: Just one little thing: its $\frac{13}{12}$, not $14$.

Comment: Yep, over $1$ by $\frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{k} \ge \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n^2-(n+1)+1}{n^2} = 1.$$
The final fraction due to there being $n^2-(n+1)+1$ terms, each of which is at least $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using some calculus you can see that $$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac{1}{k} \ge \int_{n}^{n^2} \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln(n^2) - \ln(n) = \ln(n).$$

Certainly this is larger than 1 for $n\ge 3$. For $n=1$ the claim follows automatically. For $n=2$ we check $$\frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 = \frac{6+4+3}{12} = \frac{13}{12}.$$

---

Since we know this holds for $n=2$, another approach is to show that $f(n)=\sum_{k=n}^{n^2}1/k$ is an increasing function. Since between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ we lose $1/n$ and gain $$\frac{1}{n^2+1} + \frac{1}{n^2+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ we need to show that the sum of the new terms is larger than $1/n$.

We can get a lower bound on this tail: $$\frac{1}{n^2+1} + \frac{1}{n^2+2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} > \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2}.$$ If this left term is larger than $1/n$ we win. Using some precalculus type reasoning we can see that $$\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2} \ge \frac1n$$ is equivalent to $$n^2 - n - 1 \ge 0.$$

This is satisfied for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: +1, using the integral  is the approach that can give the asymptotic expansion.

Comment: I believe if you take the error bounds seriously enough, you can show that the sum is actually $\log(n)+O(1)$.

Comment: Or even $O(1/n)$ now that I think about it.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be about Harmonic numbers en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 2):

Just another way, using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\frac1{n+k}+\frac1{n^2-k} \ge \frac4{n^2+n}$$

$$\implies 2\sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n}\frac1{n+k} \ge \frac4{n^2+n}(n^2-n+1)$$

So all we need to show is $2(n^2-n+1) \ge n^2+n  \iff (n-1)(n-2)\ge 0$
which is evidently true for integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Arithmetic-Harmonic Inequality:
$$\frac{n^2-n+1}{n+(n+1)+\cdots+n^2}\leq\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Now, the denominator of the left-hand fraction is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n}(n+k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-n+1}(n+k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-n+1}(n-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-n+1}k=\frac{n^4+n}{2}$$

Hence, we have that
$$1\leq\frac{2(n^2-n+1)}{n(n+1)}=\frac{2(n^2-n+1)^2}{n(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}=\frac{2(n^2-n+1)^2}{n^4+n}\leq\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}$$

We can recover the first inequality here from the fact that $0\leq (n-1)(n-2)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Check the number of terms!  There are $n^2-n+1 \neq n^2+1$ terms.  Still can be made to work after correcting that.

Comment: @Macavity thanks for the correction. Fixed